# In the attempt to fix line spacing with custom font, it gets rid of the font style with setParagraphAttributes

Tags: java, swing

(Edit: all fonts are reset back to this default font, Not sure the name of the font)

I have been attempting to make a window for a game I am developing that uses text based adventure. I have been able to implement custom font and I also have been able to get it all working but I am having an issue where the line spacing is way to small, so small in fact that you can't actually read some of the text... I have been using the `setParagraphAttributes` to set the line spacing but it also seems to reset the custom font, here is my code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GUI {
    public static final int sizeX = 1280;
    public static final int sizeY = 680;
    public static JTextPane textBox;

    public static JPanel createGui() {
        //Create panels
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel inventoryPanel = new JPanel();

        //Setup panel details
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeX, sizeY));
        textPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        inventoryPanel.setBackground(new Color(71, 22, 22));

        //Setup attributes
        SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();  
        MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.white);
        StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, 1.05f);

        //Create custom font
        try {
            Font customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Main/resources/font.ttf")).deriveFont(10f);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(customFont);

            textBox = new JTextPane();
            textBox.setFont(customFont);
        } catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("<Error> Font failure");
        }

        //Setup text panel
        textBox.setCharacterAttributes(attributeSet, true);
        textBox.setParagraphAttributes(set, true); //This is causing issues with the custom font
        textBox.setAutoscrolls(true);
        textBox.setEditable(true);
        textBox.setBackground(Color.black);
        textBox.setText("TextBox with some text I came up with to find out if it worked or not XD");

        //Setup GUI layout
        textPanel.add(textBox);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        textPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textPanel, FlowLayout.LEADING));
        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        mainPanel.add(inventoryPanel);

        //Return GUI to window
        return mainPanel;
    }
}
```

Having listened to a few of the responses I edited it and here is the code for the JFrame itself:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{
    public Window() {
        setTitle("Window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(GUI.createGui());
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Main/resources/Icon.png");
        setIconImage(img.getImage());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

if you have an answer, please keep it simple as I am new to java (I know window UI is a bit complex for a new java user, but I would love to see it in my game).

*Sorry if there is any weird things in the code, I am really new to java and I haven't gotten around to optimizing yet because I just want to get something that works*

Comment: Without your JFrame code and a link to the custom font, you're not likely to get much help.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will take you through the steps of creating a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.  I understand that you want to get something working, but unless each small bit of code you add to your project is understandable and correct, you're going to run into nothing but problems.

Comment: Did you test with a standard Font? That is do you have a problem with all Fonts or just the custom font? Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your problem.  We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test to see the behaviour you describe. Your question is about a JTextPane and a Font. So all you need is a frame with your text pane. All the other components are irrelevant. The foreground attributes are irrelevant. Once again, get rid of the static Swing components.

Comment: @camickr I have tested it and it does revert any other text to this default font type (Not sure what the font is called). Also, I have noticed an issue when I get rid of the static swing component that it will not add the custom font at all for some reason. I agree with you that they shouldn't be there but I can't change them without the code breaking. (I will try to figure it out later, for now I just need the basic text pane set up)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the troubles, I have solved the issue. I simply just had to register my font into a graphics environment then I had to set the style constants font family to the name of my fonts graphics environment, solution:

```java
//Creating custom font and registering it into a graphics environment
Font customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("file.ttf")).deriveFont(12f);
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(customFont);

//Setting font in the styleconstants font family
SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attributeSet, "Name Of Custom Font");
```